# IP address does not always resolve with socket.gethostbyname

Tags: python

```
import socket
import os

url = input("enter website:")
a = socket.gethostbyname(url)
print(a)

os.system('ping '+ a)
```

I have that code above but when i run it the IP address that i get from the socket.gethostbyname(url) it doesn't resolve to the website that i gave it.

Most of the websites give me a error 403.

am i missing something? any tips?

Comment: Many host records don’t have reverse lookup records. If they don’t, `ping` can’t look up the name. But why do you want it to? You already have the name, after all.

Comment: There is no one-to-one relationship between numeric IP addresses and names.

Comment: Also, `gethostbyname` doesn’t take a URL, it takes a hostname. If you prompt for a website URL, people are likely to respond with something like `https://stackoverflow.com` instead of `stackoverflow.com`, at which point they’ll get an error. If you really want to handle URLs, you have to parse them (e.g., with `urllib.parse`) to extract the name.

Comment: I attempted to do it with stackoverflow.com, enter url:stackoverflow.com
151.101.65.69

Pinging 151.101.65.69 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 151.101.65.69:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

The ping was unsuccessful with with IP address i gave it

Comment: @SirusVirus Many people disable ping on their routers, so if you try to ping their servers, you get exactly that error.